# Routes and post laravel

Tags: php, laravel, post, routes, controller

When i create the function on controller to show with method 'index' and add this route on my web.php works, but when try the form, with post method to 'login', Laravel alert me on my browser: Route [samein.login] not defined. What is my mistake? I'm new on Laravel, and not understand completely:
¿What is my error?
Controller:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Requests\loginrequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Queue\RedisQueue;

class logincontroller extends Controller
{

    public function index(){
        return view('login');
    }

    public function login( )
    {
        $credentiales = $request->getCredentials();

        if( Auth::validate($credentiales) ){
            return redirect()->to('login')->withErrors('auth.failed');
        }

        $user = Auth::getProvider()->retrieveByCredentials($credentiales);

        Auth::login($user);
        return $this->authenticated($request,$user);
    }

    public function authenticated (Request $request,$user){
        return redirect('accountModule.indexusers');
    }
}
```

Route on web.php :

```php
Route::resource('/samein',logincontroller::class);
```

Template:

```php
@extends('components\header')
<section class="vh-100">
  <div class="container-fluid h-custom">
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
      <div class="col-4">
          <img src="{{ URL::asset('img/logo.png') }}"
          class="img-fluid" height="500">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-6 col-xl-4 offset-xl-1">
        <form action="{{ route('samein.login') }}" method="POST">
          @csrf
          <!-- Email input -->
          <div class="form-outline mb-4">
            <input type="email" name="username" class="form-control form-control-lg"
              placeholder="Enter a valid email address" />
            <label class="form-label" for="form3Example3">Usuario</label>
          </div>

          <!-- Password input -->
          <div class="form-outline mb-3">
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control form-control-lg"
              placeholder="Enter password" />
            <label class="form-label" for="form3Example4">Contraseña</label>
          </div>

          <div class="text-rigth text-lg-start mt-4 pt-2">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
              style="padding-left: 2.5rem; padding-right: 2.5rem;">Iniciar Sesión</button>
          </div>

        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/trktp.png

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller - login is not a named route that a resource controller creates. Any additional routes will need to be created manually

Comment: The `login` method isn't hooked up to your `ResourceController` by default, only the named methods that Aynber linked are. You'll need to define a `Route::post('samein/login', [logincontroller::class, 'login')->name('samein.login');` (or similar, syntax is Laravel-version specific) to hook that up. Also, class names are `PascalCase`; `LoginController`, not `logincontroller`.

Comment: You are not using any named route.. In your form you uses a named route route('samein.login') But there is not route with that name in your routes file. You should have one route with that name like Route::post('preferred-url', [controller, action])->name('samein.login')

Comment: Also as @TimLewis said as per PSR standard the classname has to be in pascal case for autoloading to work properly.

Comment: Thank you for helping me, the problem was solved by assigning a name to the route, and thanks for the correction on how the controllers should be named.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resource controllers have default *route names* assigned to them by Laravel.

Instead of:❌

```php
{{ route('samein.login') }}
```

Use this:✅

```php
{{ route('samein.store') }}
```

[Actions Handled By Resource Controller](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller)

> `POST` |  `/photos` | `store` | `photos.store`

##### Addendum

[Naming Resource Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#restful-naming-resource-routes)

> By default, all resource controller actions have a route name;
> however, you can override these names by passing a `names` array with
> your desired route names:

> ```php
> use App\Http\Controllers\LoginController;
>  
> Route::resource('samein', LoginController::class)->names([
>     'store' => 'samein.login'
> ]);
> ```

Comment: Good, if he has only one POST route, but won't that be ambiguous for multiple POST routes?

Comment: @RakeshMehta The **Addendum** section in my edited answer should be able to fulfil that requirement.

Comment: That seems cool Steve..